# A Hooks Context give me en error for loop render why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm beginning to learn React Js. I was trying to create a auth with hooks.
But I recived en error:

> ```
> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside
> ```
>
> componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of
>   nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This is my code I tried to simplify the components, I hope it's clear

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect( () => {
        //const token    = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );
        //const userName = localStorage.getItem( 'userName' );
        console.log('useEffect Auth Provider');
        console.log(currentUser);
    }, [] );
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={
            [currentUser, setCurrentUser]
          }
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
}
```

When I try to login in Login.js :

```
export const Login = () => {

    const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useContext( AuthContext );


     // Login
     const handleLogin = (event) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
         console.log(email.value, password.value);

         const siteUrl = clientConfig.serverUrl;

         const loginData = {
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value
        };

        axios.post( `${siteUrl}/api/users/login`, loginData )
                .then( res => {
                    setCurrentUser(res.data);
                    console.log(res.data);      
        });
     }



     if (currentUser) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
      }

      else {
    return (

          <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
              <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"></input>
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="**************"></input>
              <button type="submit">Login</button>                    
           </form>

    );
  }
};
```

App.js:

```
function App() {



  return (
    <AuthProvider>
       <Router>
          <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>

  );

}

export default App;
```

// PrivateRoute

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks to anybody who want to help me.
Marco.Italy

Comment: When does the error occur? After you press submit?

Comment: yes! when try to  axios.post( `${siteUrl}/api/users/login`, loginData )
                .then( res => {
                    setCurrentUser(res.data);  <------------ ERROR
                    console.log(res.data);      
        });

Comment: Could you provide a CodeSandbox with the code? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-microservice-275q5?fontsize=14

Comment: I've found out the problem. Check solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dubinsky-yhpcl

The problem was in the way you were accessing your current user on your PrivateRoute. It was coming back as `undefined`.

`const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);`

You can't destructure an array like that. So I changed to this:

`const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useContext(AuthContext);`

NOTE: I know you don't need the `setCurrentUser` on `PrivateRoute`. But it's just a way to make it work clearly as is. You can also do it like this:

`const [currentUser] = useContext(AuthContext);` // THIS WORKS WHEN YOU'RE GETTING THE FIRST ARRAY VALUE

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("Rendering PrivateRoute...");
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useContext(AuthContext);     // <-------------
  console.log("currentUser: " + currentUser);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer.

Comment: No problem. One thing that helps debug and understand what is being rendered is to add some `console.log()` around. Like in every component that I create, I immediately add a line inside of it as: `console.log('Rendering ComponentX...);` Also do that on every `useEffect` and basically wherever you think it's necessary. That's how I've found out that the problem was in your `PrivateRoute` component. Then I logged `currentUser` and saw it was `undefined`.